# Call a keyword with specific time interval in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I have a keyword which checks, if a button value is `Completed`, once it is found, I want that keyword to stop and return the status.
However the the button value `Completed` is not fixed to any time interval.
I want to call the keyword recursively to check for value of button at every 3 minutes.

```
   *** Test Case ***
   Navigate to menu    Home  Status
   #Something here to call the keywrod `Check run status` for every 3 
   minutes until ${passd} is true or 30 minutes are passed. 


***Keywrod***
 Check run status
${btnValue}  Get Text   //button[@id="btn_status"]  
${passed} =   Run Keyword And Return Status   Should be Equal   ${btnValue}   
Completed   
[Return]   ${passed}
```

How to iterate this with time interval & How can we achieve this with  robotframework?

Answer (score 0):

`Wait Until Keyword Succeeds`

Docs [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds).